# Drawing text on an NSImage

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, nsimage

I am struggling to find any good tutorials or posts about how to draw some text onto an NSImage. I have a feeling this is a pretty simple process but I just can't work it out!

I already have an NSImage and i need to end up with a manipulated NSImage at the end.

Has anybody got any clue how I can do this?

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 3):

There could be an easier way, but personally I would go about it by using the following methods.

To put the text on your image, use the NSString method:

```
- (void)drawInRect:(NSRect)aRect withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
```

Then, (I'm assuming you want this retained in your image), use the NSImage method:

```
NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[myView dataWithPDFInsideRect:[oldImage frame];
```